Tag or force at third base
A runner is at second with a runner on first.  The ball is hit.   Both runners advance.  There is a throw to third, but the runner touches third base before the ball is secured, but happens to go off third base with his momentum. Third baseman secures the ball and touches third base before runner gets back on base.   Is runner out or did he need to be tagged?

MLB rule 5.09(b)(6):

He or the next base is tagged before he touches the next base, after he has been forced to advance by reason of the batter becoming a runner.

The runner touched the base, so they cannot be put out by tagging the base.
